# alias redirection not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, debian

I've put a simple alias `Alias /file1 /dir1/file1` in my vhost and it's not working, the apache log states that the file `/file1` doesn't exists...

What's peculiar about my configuration is that I've got vhost configured on url-basis with the ServerPath directive.

I've got a vhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName sub.domain.com
     ...
</VirtualHost>
```

and another :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName sub.domain.com
     ServerPath /ref1
     ...
     Alias /file1 /dir1/file1
</VirtualHost>
```

So the behaviour expected is that when I type `sub.domain.com/ref1/`, I'm redirected to `sub.domain.com/ref1/dir1/file1`.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) works. Alias maps a **URL** path to a **physical file/directory path**. This means, if you have:

```
Alias /file1 /dir1/file1
```

When you go to `http://sub.domain.com/file1` you get served the file on the harddrive at `/dir1/file1`. What you are looking for may be mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file1$ /dir1/file1 [L]
```

Comment: I apologize if I was unclear, the physical path of file1 is `/dir1/file1`, so with this alias directive, the url with `/file1` should correspond to the physical file `/dir1/file1`, shouldn't it ?